# Toggle only one instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not exactly sure what it is that i need, so the following explanation may not be clear - please let me know if not.

I want to `slideToggle` a specific clicked div, the code i currently have of course slideToggle's all instances of the div with a class of `.open-statement`, but i want to only toggle the one instance of this class that appears inside the parent div `.agenda-content`. There will be numerous instances of `.open-statement` on the page eventually, but only one of them should toggle (the one that's inside the current clicked div).

HTML

```
        <div class="agenda-content">
            <div class="row stance-row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 no_padding">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    Obamacare
                    <button class="btn btn-orange">Remove Stance</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    Add jQuery UI here
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    34
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 no_padding">
                    Wayne Rooney
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-row-style">
                <div class="open-statement">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <div class="your-statement">
                            <textarea placeholder="Please write your statement"></textarea>
                            <button class="btn btn-orange">Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7 no_padding">
                        <div class="statement-actions">
                            <button class="btn btn-alert">Deactivate</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-lt-secondary">View Debates</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-orange">Unsupport</button>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row stance-row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 no_padding">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    Raise Minimum Wage
                    <button class="btn btn-orange">Take a Stance</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    Add jQuery UI here
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    34
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 no_padding">
                    Stephen King
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-row-style">
                <div class="open-statement">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <div class="your-statement">
                            <textarea placeholder="Please write your statement"></textarea>
                            <button class="btn btn-orange">Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-7 no_padding">
                        <div class="statement-actions">
                            <button class="btn btn-alert">Deactivate</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-lt-secondary">View Debates</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-orange">Unsupport</button>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".stance-row").click(function () {
    $(".agenda-content").find(".open-statement").slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ and http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/ (and all the rest of the tutorial).

Comment: Thanks Felix, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.agenda-content` is the parent of all `.open-statement`. You need to be more specific. Use `.next` and `.find()` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stance-row").click(function () {
        $(this).next().find(".open-statement").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just need to change your code to get respective next item.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".stance-row").click(function () {
   $(this).next("div.row").find(".open-statement").slideToggle();
 });
});
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/6GMj7/

Cheers,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`:

```
$(this).closest(".agenda-content").find(".open-statement").slideToggle();
```

Comment: I knew i needed `this` but wasn't sure how to incorporate it in the context i needed. The code you mention above doesn't seem to work - perhaps i'm missing something?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Setup a JS fiddle as well

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the user would click .stance-row. No errors in console.

Comment: @NikkiMather -- You did wrap this code in your existing click handler right?